# How to add menù section to my WordPress template?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, templates

I am pretty new in WordPress blog and I am developing a blog with this template:
http://scorejava.com/wordpress351

As you can see at the top of the page there is a "menù" that only show the page in the site (at this moment: "Home" and "Pagina di esempio").

This menù is showed by the following lines of code into the header.php file:

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>
```

So I think that this is not a true menù but only a list of the statics pages present on my blog.

If, in the administrator dashboard I go to the menù section in the "Position of themes" square say me that: **"This theme has no support for menus but it is possible use the personalized menu widget to add every created menu in the sidebar"**

So I think that my template have no definied a true menù section on the top (but only a list for the static pages). Can I add a true section where add a true menu? How can I do?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: start here: [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to edit functions.php andding the following line

`<?php register_nav_menu( 'primary', 'Primary Menu' );  ?>`

1. Then go in admin section Apearence-Menus and create one menu
2. In the header replace `<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&depth=1'); ?>`
   for example (the primary menu) with:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>`

more details for nav_menu [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)